# How to rotate APP delegate window's label in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added one label on appDelegate windows for MPMovie player SRT handling but for Ios_Version7 it is not working .
I have handle device orientation for landscape/portrait .
I know windows object is not rotating once you rotate your view but Do we rotate it according to screen rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

if you have navigation controller, do this

```
[navigationController.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: Thanks Shebin Koshy, I have used your code but it is not working me for ios_Version7 still label is rotating in my simulator

Comment: @VivekGajbe you have navigation controller??

Comment: Yes I have , Does it effects on label orientation?

Comment: @VivekGajbe sure. i updated my answer. do what i mentioned